# Forms API in eclipse rcp4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I'm trying to use FormToolkit for creating components and add them in section widgets for better look n feel in RCP4. But with this nothing is rendered on wizard page at runtime and there is no error also. Questions:

Is it possible to have forms api into Eclipse RCP4?

Comment: No, the forms classes are 3.x compatibility mode code.

Comment: Is there any way to do same thing in RCP4?

Comment: Colours and fonts can be done with CSS styling. Some of the form controls like Section mainly just depend on SWT and JFace so it may be possible to make a workable copy of them from a copy of the source code.